# Diferent Paths to save files (Windows)

Tags: windows, path

I'm having a problem with windows to save my files, I do have no idea why my files are saved in one path like this:

C:\Users\jesus\OneDrive\Documentos

It's creaded by One Drive (I think), but I do have no idea how to restore it to the defualt which be

C:\Users\jesus\Documents

I have tried many stuff but nothing work.
My problem is that even when my files appear there in the first one, I can not see in the second, and the problems beging when I want to do programming stuff, nothing what I save it's identified.
What I mean it's for example when I used the jupyter notebook and I save the file it doesn't appear in my documents, but only when I look in the second path I'm able to found my files.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is a question for SuperUser, not StackOverflow (StackOverflow is more for programming related questions, whereas SU is more aligned towards this sort of stuff)
2. [This Guide](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-default-save-location-windows-10) goes over how to do it if you don't really care about having your files automatically back up to One Drive in the future
3. [This Other Guide](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/move-onedrive-folder) goes over how to move your OneDrive folder along with the 'Documents' Directory